# Python kmeans package installation failure

Tags: python, k-means

I tried to install **kmeans** package but failed!

I've used so many different ways to solve the issue but none of them works. Hope that someone have idea of how to deal with the issue! Thanks a lot!!

## The error message is as below

```
Collecting kmeans
  Using cached https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/d1/7e/87d12a99d7ccfd2c85b
19899012177e1718c2d6c0148fad421523160e84b/kmeans-1.0.2.tar.gz
Installing collected packages: kmeans
  Running setup.py install for kmeans ... error
    Complete output from command c:\users\AAA\appdata\local\programs\python\pyt
hon36\python.exe -u -c "import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AAA\\A
ppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip-install-hjr78jwg\\kmeans\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize,
 'open', open)(__file__);code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(comp
ile(code, __file__, 'exec'))" install --record C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\
pip-record-rek9bpzw\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --com
pile:
    running install
    running build
    running build_py
    creating build
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kmeans
    copying kmeans\performance.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kmeans
    copying kmeans\tests.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kmeans
    copying kmeans\__init__.py -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kmeans
    running egg_info
    writing kmeans.egg-info\PKG-INFO
    writing dependency_links to kmeans.egg-info\dependency_links.txt
    writing top-level names to kmeans.egg-info\top_level.txt
    reading manifest file 'kmeans.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    writing manifest file 'kmeans.egg-info\SOURCES.txt'
    copying kmeans\lib.c -> build\lib.win-amd64-3.6\kmeans
    running build_ext
    building 'kmeans/lib' extension
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release
    creating build\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\kmeans
    C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\BIN\x86_amd64\cl.exe

/c /nologo /Ox /W3 /GL /DNDEBUG /MD -Ic:\users\AAA\appdata\local\programs\pytho
n\python36\include -Ic:\users\AAA\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\includ
e "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\VC\INCLUDE" "-IC:\Progr
am Files (x86)\Windows Kits\10\include\10.0.10240.0\ucrt" "-IC:\Program Files (x
86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\shared" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\
include\um" "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\Windows Kits\8.1\include\winrt" /Tckmeans/
lib.c /Fobuild\temp.win-amd64-3.6\Release\kmeans/lib.obj -Wno-error=declaration-
after-statement -O3 -std=c99
    cl : Command line error D8021 : invalid numeric argument '/Wno-error=declara
tion-after-statement'
    error: command 'C:\\Program Files (x86)\\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\\VC\\B
IN\\x86_amd64\\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

    ----------------------------------------
Command "c:\users\AAA\appdata\local\programs\python\python36\python.exe -u -c "
import setuptools, tokenize;__file__='C:\\Users\\AAA\\AppData\\Local\\Temp\\pip
-install-hjr78jwg\\kmeans\\setup.py';f=getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(__file__)
;code=f.read().replace('\r\n', '\n');f.close();exec(compile(code, __file__, 'exe
c'))" install --record C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-record-rek9bpzw\inst
all-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error
code 1 in C:\Users\AAA\AppData\Local\Temp\pip-install-hjr78jwg\kmeans\
```

====

Comment: Is it guaranteed to work on windows? The error comes from compilation. A short skim of the project makes me wonder why you would want to use it and not high-quality alternatives like the one within scipy or better: scikit-learn?

Answer (score 0):

Try downloading the .tar.gz file from pypi.org and then in cmd go to the directory with the file and do

```
pip install <file name>
```